# How to obtain transaction creation time for Ethereum transactions using web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, etherscan, web3.py

I am interested in analysing transaction latency in Ethereum (time it takes from creating the transaction until it has been added to a block).
I have been looking at Web3 (link https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/), and i can only find the time when the transactions is added to a block (block timestamp), but not when it was created by its submitter.

My question is there any clue to find the actual creation time for ethereum transactions, so that i can estimate the transaction latency?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any clue to find the actual creation time for ethereum transactions

Unless you are the submitter of the transaction yourself and know it, then no.

Comment: Thank you! then i am just wondering if we could look at transactions at mempool record their apperance time and then see when they will be included in a block. Is this still possible?